# VBA to copy the column and paste as new row with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a column value and paste as a new row after each row as a merged cell. I have started my step towards this and managed to add a blank row after each row on specified sheet with range but need further on copying the column cell value and paste into each row.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
 Sub Macro1()
 Dim LastRow, RowNumber As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 'FOLLOWING WORKS WITH RANGED AND SPECIFIED SPREADSHEET
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Asset")
With ws
 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      For RowNumber = LastRow To 11 Step -1 'FROM WHAT ROW TO START THE INSERT ROW BLANK
    .Rows(RowNumber).Insert
Next RowNumber
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**Update:**
Thank you so much.

I am working on increasing the row height dynamically. I have an another sheet ("VariablSheet") with dictionary of what row height should be if the LEN characters of row exceeds certain value. How do I make this dynamic?

So far, I have the below:

```
Dim var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, 
var12, var13, var14, var15, var16, var17, var18, var19, var20, var21, 
var22, var23, var24, var25, var26 As Variant
var1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VariablSheet").Range("F4").Value
var2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VariablSheet").Range("F5").Value....
        If Len(.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1).Value) > var6 Then 'TS Added 
  to adjust row height
                .Rows(RowNumber + 1).RowHeight = 75 ' TS 6 Line
        ElseIf Len(.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1).Value) > var5 Then 'TS 
     Added to adjust row height
                .Rows(RowNumber + 1).RowHeight = 65 ' TS 5 Line
        ElseIf Len(.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1).Value) > var4 Then 'TS 
    Added to adjust row height
                .Rows(RowNumber + 1).RowHeight = 52 ' TS 4 Line
        ElseIf Len(.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1).Value) > var3 Then 'TS 
 Added to adjust row height
                .Rows(RowNumber + 1).RowHeight = 39 ' TS 3 Line
        ElseIf Len(.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1).Value) > var2 Then 'TS 
 Added to adjust row height
                .Rows(RowNumber + 1).RowHeight = 26 ' TS 2 Line
        ElseIf Len(.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1).Value) > var1 Then  'TS 
  Added to adjust row height
                .Rows(RowNumber + 1).RowHeight = 15 ' TS Single Line
```

Do you know what is the efficient way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Record a macro doing the transformations manually and this will give you a starting point to be able to make the code more dynamic

Comment: @Tragamor thanks. I have already working on it and struggling to make it dynamic

Comment: Then worth updating the question with the recorded macro of inserting, copying and merging the cells.

Comment: I'll give you a hand. Let me work out the solution and I will post in a few mins.

Answer (score 1):

Recorded macro

```
Sub Macro1()
'
    Rows("4:4").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.Paste
    Range("A4:C4").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
End Sub
```

So cutting out what is unnecessary and making it useable in a loop we get:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowNumber As Long
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Asset")
    Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = 6

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For RowNumber = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
            .Rows(RowNumber + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown              'Want inserted row below
            .Cells(RowNumber, 4).Cut Destination:=.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1)
            With .Range(.Cells(RowNumber + 1, 1), .Cells(RowNumber + 1, 3))
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        Next RowNumber
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I will this a go. I was looking at offset property to select the data.

Comment: I have used your approach on mine and it has worked. Thank you. Further, I am looking to increase to increase the row height dynamic as currently I have to put a condition for each. I have updated the question for more clarity. What is the best way to make it dynamic with the another sheet which holds the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I commented in code what steps i took to make the sample work correctly.

```
Sub Macro1()
 Dim LastRow, RowNumber As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim valueToCopy As String


 
 'FOLLOWING WORKS WITH RANGED AND SPECIFIED SPREADSHEET
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Asset")
 
 Range("A1").Select ' select the first cell in the worksheet.


'get the value from the first row. in column A
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow + 2

'get the value to copy to the next row.
valueToCopy = Rows(i).Cells(1, 4).Value

'insert a row below the current row
Rows(i + 1).Select

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Rows(i + 1).Cells(1, 1).Select
Rows(i + 1).Cells(1, 1).Value = valueToCopy
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4)).Select



With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
i = i + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

I started with a spreadsheet like this.
[image]

end result looks like this .
[image]